# Настройка Visual Studio 2022 на создание новых полей C# по заданному шаблону

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Юзаю `Quick actions and refactoring` когда пишу код. Интересует непосредственно момент с автогенерацией поля. Например:

```
public MyClass(string value)
{

}
```

Студия после быстрых действий создает следующую структуру:

```
private readonly string value;

public MyClass(string value)
{
   this.value = value;
}
```

Но! Майкрософт [рекомендует](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#camel-case) называть поля с префиксом `_`, чего студия сама не делает. Как можно настроить студию так, чтобы поля генерировались с префиксом `_`, но при этом не меняла название параметров в конструкторе? Хочу в итоге получить следующий результат после `Quick actions and refactoring`:

```
private readonly string _value;

public MyClass(string value)
{
   _value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого следует задать соответствующий стиль для имен полей. Это можно сделать, открыв настройки Main menu → Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Code Style → Naming.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тогда при правке будет сразу предлагаться нужный стиль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо =)